# How would you find the Cartesian Equation that fits the following requirements?

Tags: vectors, 3d

The Cartesian equation must pass through the point $(3,-1,2)$ and must be perpendicular to the LOI of the planes $3x-2y+1=0$ and $3x+4z-5=0$ 
Vectors was never really my strong suit, if anyone could help me that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors normal to your planes are $(3,-2,0)$ and $(3,0,4)$
Find their cross product $$ (3,-2,0) \times (3,0,4) = (8,-12,6)$$
which is a vector parallel to the LOI . Using the given point the LOI is
$$(x,y,z)= (3,-1,2)+t(8,-12,6)$$

To convert to a Cartesian equation eliminate $t$ in the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
x=3+8t & \\
y=-1-12t& \\
z=2+6t &
\end{cases}$$